# Debugging memory on Android

Tags: android, debugging, memory, garbage-collection

I have an ANR on Android and am trying to investigate it's cause. I suspect low memory.

There is a memory part of ANR dump:

```
Done Dumping histograms
young concurrent copying paused:    Sum: 29.831ms 99% C.I. 28us-8000us Avg: 298.310us Max: 13177us
young concurrent copying freed-bytes: Avg: 8284KB Max: 20MB Min: 138KB
Freed-bytes histogram: 0:11,2560:19,5120:14,7680:21,10240:17,12800:11,15360:6,20480:1
young concurrent copying total time: 2.090s mean time: 20.905ms
young concurrent copying freed: 7852789 objects with total size 809MB
young concurrent copying throughput: 3.75732e+06/s / 387MB/s  per cpu-time: 488687843/s / 466MB/s
Average minor GC reclaim bytes ratio 0.672043 over 100 GC cycles
Average minor GC copied live bytes ratio 0.0321947 over 147 minor GCs
Cumulative bytes moved 20469720
Cumulative objects moved 401417
Peak regions allocated 130 (32MB) / 2048 (512MB)
Total time spent in GC: 3.446s
Mean GC size throughput: 275MB/s per cpu-time: 372MB/s
Mean GC object throughput: 2.50472e+06 objects/s
Total number of allocations 8948336
Total bytes allocated 974MB
Total bytes freed 948MB
Free memory 1001KB
Free memory until GC 1001KB
Free memory until OOME 486MB
Total memory 26MB
Max memory 512MB
Zygote space size 3164KB
Total mutator paused time: 33.235ms
Total time waiting for GC to complete: 58.924ms
Total GC count: 113
Total GC time: 3.446s
Total blocking GC count: 2
Total blocking GC time: 63.099ms
Histogram of GC count per 10000 ms: 0:605,1:68,2:4,3:3,4:1,5:1,7:1,11:1
Histogram of blocking GC count per 10000 ms: 0:682,1:2
Native bytes total: 146822268 registered: 272188
Total native bytes at last GC: 145194612
```

Could someone help, is there "low memory"? Free memory 1001KB - it's low, but I haven't found the exactly meaning of these entries.